# How to bring menu option infront of all DIVs

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface

I am trying to implement the kind of menu as in this link : http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/01/19/Create-Vimeo-like-top-navigation.aspx

I am able to get the menu but some sub menu options are hidden behind another div so I am not able to view those options.

I also tried changing the position and z-index of every `li` or `ul` still no success.

Could you let me know if I have to change any other CSS property?

Regards,

Satya

Comment: Could you please show your CSS and HTML code so that we can figure out what's wrong?

Comment: z-index should do that for you. Do you have an example of your code? Or even better, a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works with position atttribue.
Do you have:

position: relative

Just a thought...